# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I saw plenty of questions related to 
**TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined** but none of them are helpful to solve my error.

My requirement is onClick button(like: ng-click="addRow(tester.devices)" ) I have to call a function-

In which if already devicelist is present/calling then no need to define `_scope.tester.devices = []` otherwise `_scope.tester.devices = [];`is defined to avoid error: 
Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined

My code as follows

```
_scope.addRow = function (list) {
        _scope.uniqueId = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) * 10000);
        if (_scope.tester.devices) {
            _scope.tester.devices.unshift({
                'name': '',
                'id': '',
                'uniqueId': _scope.uniqueId,
            });


        } else {
            _scope.tester.devices = [];
            _scope.tester.devices.unshift({
                'name': '',
                'id': '',
                'uniqueId': _scope.uniqueId,
            });
        }
        _scope.modifyField[list[0].uniqueId] = true;
    }
```

Edit1: I defined $scope as _scope. So this is not problem.

**This question solved**

Answer (score 1):

Pass array to the function, seems like you are passing wrong parameter to the function _scope.addRow()

it worked fine for me after passing array to the function.

Comment: i define $scope as _scope in controller function.The problem is with _scope.modifyField. i Solved it. Thank for help

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by modifying  `_scope.modifyField[list[0].uniqueId] = true;` to `_scope.modifyField[_scope.uniqueId] = true;` .

Unfortunately, i unable to delete my question as someone invested time on this as per Stack Overflow rules.

The code as follows:

```
 _scope.addRow = function (list) {
        _scope.uniqueId = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) * 10000);
        if (_scope.tester.devices) {
            _scope.tester.devices.unshift({
                'name': '',
                'id': '',
                'uniqueId': _scope.uniqueId,
            });
             _scope.modifyField[list[0].uniqueId] = true;

        } else {
            _scope.tester.devices = [];
            _scope.tester.devices.unshift({
                'name': '',
                'id': '',
                'uniqueId': _scope.uniqueId,
            });
        }
        _scope.modifyField[_scope.uniqueId] = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
Are you sure your function argument ('list') is an array? It seems undefined.

Comment: No, it is the argument of the function, who is undefined. The error was thrown because you try to access to it like an array. Now if you doesn't need it anymore you can remove it from the method definition : `code` _scope.addRow = function () { `code`